# Speed up writing a ton of JSON data to disk

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, core-data, file-io

I have a loop of maybe 40k records that basically calls.  It seems that the writing to file is REALLY SLOW.  If I Iterate through the loop its almost instant so I realize its not the core-data iteration that is slow is the file writing process.  Is there a better way to stream data to a file than what I'm doing here?

```
#ifndef jsonAppend
#define jsonAppend(X) [outStream write:[[X dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding ] bytes] maxLength:[X lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]
#endif



NSOutputStream *outStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:tempFilePath append:NO];

    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{

// Open an output stream to write to.
[outStream open];

// Other code ... blablabla

for (AHRSMessage *msg in results)
{

    @autoreleasepool
    {

        [NSJSONSerialization writeJSONObject:msg.attributesAsDictionary toStream:outStream options:0 error:&error];
        jsonAppend(@",\n");

        i++;  // MessageCounter


        // Update UI only sometimes
        if (i % 100)
        {

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
            {
                @autoreleasepool {


                    float pct = i / recordCount ;
                    NSString *pctStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02.0f%%", pct * 100.0];
                    [[weakSelf percentLabel] setText:pctStr];
                    [[weakSelf parsingProgress] setProgress:pct animated:YES];

                    /* - Animate inner circle on units of 1% - */
                    int singPctMsgCount = recordCount / 100;
                    float fastParse = (i % singPctMsgCount) / (float)singPctMsgCount;
                    [[weakSelf fastParsingProgress] setProgress:fastParse animated:YES]     ;

                    [weakSelf updateUI];

                }
            });

        }

    }
} // end for loop
```

});

Comment: How many objects are you writing, and how large is each?  Is there any reason you don't write them as a single JSON array?

Comment: The resulting file is about 18megs  when I tried to do it on shot i ran into memory issues - say 44k objects?

Comment: And you realize you can (with a few precautions) do the file writing in background, right?

Comment: The whole block of code i posted is in a dispatch_async background thread

Comment: So each object is around 500 bytes?

Comment: Its variable.  Some messages are quite long some are small.  I'm getting data from a sensor parsing it out and storing both the raw data and the parsed data.  500 is reasonable on average.

Comment: In my experience what you're doing can be pretty slow -- several minutes, possibly.  (I don't offhand have an example I can scale to, but I've seen some of that order of magnitude in the past.)

Comment: Whenever having "performance" issues, you should at least backup your assertions with Instruments. I can imagine, that the implementation of `NSJSONSerialization` writing into a NSStream *can* be slow (serializing into NSStream isn't the fastest thing around). But you need to prove that! There are possibly faster alternatives, e.g. third party JSON parsers, which firstly can serialize much faster, and use a more performant approach to write into a file.

Comment: I figured i could just manually write a "parser" of sorts to convert things into strings perhaps

Comment: In instruments +NSJSONSerialization is taking up about 39% of the cpu time so I'm going to say thats probably the culprit and when i break it down most of the time i sussed on : [NSCFOutputstream hasSpaceAvailable] (23%) - maybe its time to make a manual JSON "thingy"

Comment: You can try writing to a buffer (`outputStreamToBuffer:capacity:`) and when its full (or nearing it) write the buffer to a file. this should reduce disk access.

Comment: There are JSON toolkits that claim to be faster than NSJSONSerialization.

Comment: @HotLicks in my experience they usually end up not being faster. `NSJSONSerialization` is pretty close to as fast as possible.

Comment: There is at least one that claims to be faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's only 18MB, just serialise it to an `NSMutableData` object, then write that to disk.

That should be extremely fast. `NSMutableData` can trivially handle amounts of data that do not even fit in flash memory (assuming you have a 64 bit processor), let alone in RAM on an iOS device.

Like this:

```
dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{

  NSMutableData *outData = [NSMutableData data];

  // Other code ... blablabla

  for (AHRSMessage *msg in results)
  {

      @autoreleasepool
      {
          [outData appendData:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:msg.attributesAsDictionary options:0 error:&error];

          i++;  // MessageCounter


          // Update UI only sometimes
          if (i % 100)
          {

              dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
              {
                  @autoreleasepool {

                      ... update progress bar ...

                  }
              });

          }

      }
  } // end for loop

  [outData writeToURL:outURL atomically:YES];
});
```

Also, I would not use `if (i % 100)` to decide it's time to update the progress bar. Instead I would use:

```
CFTimeInterval lastProgressUpdate = CACurrentMediaTime();

for (  ... ) {
  ...

  if (CACurrentMediaTime() - lastProgressUpdate > 0.02) { // 1/60th of a second. Which is the refresh rate of most LCD screens
    ... update progress bar ....

    lastProgressUpdate = CACurrentMediaTime()
  }
}
```

Comment: I will try this when I get into work today!  I have HIGH HOPES!! :)  Thanks for the suggestion.